# Access path is denied for image loading

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My image location is a network path. When I host my Visual Studio 2012 application in IIS 7.5, the image isn't loading. Where is the problem? I give full permission to that folder in the security tab.

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path `'\\suresh-pc\Share\NPRPICS\Cam0101_02\2015-01-19\04481766r.png'` is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.